# Typescript compiler does not give error if we pass invalid parameters to override abstract method in derived class

Tags: typescript

```
abstract class Base {
  public name: string;
  public abstract greet(message: string): string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Person extends Base {
  public greet(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}

const p = new Person("Bob");
console.log(p.greet());
```

no parameter is pass to greet() in Person class...still typescript successfully compile code...

please note "strictFunctionTypes": true is set in tsconfig.json

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? It seems like this is an issue with TypeScript and not a code issue that we can help you with per se.

Comment: right, actually I was expecting typescript to give me error...i don't want compile code if user has not implemented correctly.

Comment: I would suggest [opening a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new/choose)

Comment: done, I have created issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39598

Comment: The code is perfectly type safe and correct. Why should it be an error? Just because you can pass a parameter, doesn't mean that an implementation is obligated to use it.

Comment: Hi, code is not correct...greet() method expected single argument in derived class...which is not implement correctly as pr base class structure.

Comment: @SatishChauhan can you explain why that would not be type safe?

Comment: greet() method is not implement correctly as par base class declaration...

Comment: This is more of a language design grievance than an actual bug. JavaScript at its core allows for this kind of flexible behavior (i.e. ignoring unused parameters). IMO this just comes with the territory of using JavaScript (or any variant/superset thereof).

Comment: received response, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

If your implementation can work with fewer parameters, then this is absolutely fine and acceptable. sound logical